# I am trying to use selenium in pycharm to open firefox. I Have no idea what the problem is

Tags: python, pycharm, geckodriver

I am trying to use selenium in pycharm to open firefox. I Have no idea what the problem is.

-I have installed geckodriver in the correct PATH. (/usr/local/bin)
-I am using pop_os 20.04 LTS

***when I run***

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'/usr/local/bin')
```

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/elliot/PycharmProjects/IG/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/bin': '/usr/local/bin'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/elliot/PycharmProjects/IG/igbot.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'/usr/local/bin')

  File "/home/elliot/PycharmProjects/IG/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()

  File "/home/elliot/PycharmProjects/IG/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'bin' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
Process finished with exit code 1*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GeckoDriver is used to control Firefox and you are trying to use Chrome

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(...
#                  ^^^^^^ ???
```

Either use ChromeDriver or switch to Firefox.

Passing `r'/usr/local/bin'` to `Chrome` constructor makes no sense, you can omit it assuming GeckoDriver or ChromeDriver can be found in `PATH`.

There is a nice library to automate tedious task of drivers management, see [webdriver-manager](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager).

Try going through "Installation" and "Getting Started" chapters of [selenium-python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) docs.